# with sessionStore and webSockets, are cookies still needed?

Tags: javascript, session, cookies, websocket

if the following conditions are met:

1. all pages are static (eg, templates to be filled in via websocket data)
2. all pages are public
3. session id and status communicated through websocket
4. client session state stored via sessionStorage and/or localStorage

is there still a need for cookies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the pages are 100% static then there is no state, so the question becomes moot, since no mechanism at all is required for preserving state across requests.

However, if any part of the pages are dynamic then cookies may still be necessary for preserving state across multiple sessions. Since cookies are stored client side but passed to the server with every request they are a mechanism for synchronizing client and server state. Of course, you could implement this via an AJAX request and localStorage yourself if you wanted to.

Comment: great comment on question becoming moot and the central issue of preserving state.

Answer (score 2):

The localStorage/sessionStore can indeed replace cookie Storage. Both are on the client.

The neat thing about cookies is that they are auto appended to any HTTP request. There is absolutely nothing to do from a coding standpoint. But since you want to use websockets, it doesn't apply - you will still need to do wiring with the sessionid stored in the localStorage.

So the answer to your question is "No" you don't need cookies in your scenario

Comment: right - and in `sockjs` cookies are not accessible for security reasons - so why bother